# passing adb output to variable in bash script

Tags: android, bash, shell, apk, adb

im trying to create bash script to install split APKs manually with adb shell
that requires to get session id using the command bellow

command

`SESSION='pm install-create -S 42211368'`

this will output something like : `Success: created install session [547376362]`

547376362 will be the session ID

I want to pass 547376362 into SESSION Variable

`sh < pm install-write -S 24628703 ${SESSION} 0 /sdcard/YTAPKM/base.apk`

so result shall be "sh < pm install-write -S 24628703 **547376362**  0 /sdcard/YTAPKM/base.apk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` is sufficient for this.

```sh
SESSION=$(pm install-create -S 42211368 | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
sh < pm install-write -S 24628703 ${SESSION} 0 /sdcard/YTAPKM/base.apk
```

To explain what's happening a bit:

- `grep -E` uses "extended" regular expressions (easier to work with)
- `grep -o` outputs only the matching part, the integer in this case
- `SESSION=$(some_cmd)` stores the stdout from `some_cmd` to the variable `SESSION`, and allows for pipes and such too

Comment: Ok that worked now i have the session id inside $session but I got another issue
On second line I get Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "286876766"

Comment: @AhmedBadeeb I'm afraid Java isn't my area of expertise. That error may merit another question tagged with [java]

Comment: i got it working by doing this $((SESSION)) , also Thanks <3